# Pipeline run check from different ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

We need to make sure that below scenarios should be working.

- same subscription with different Azure Data Factory
- different subscription with different Azure Data Factory

Please provide your pros and cons each statement.

Answer (score 0):

As long as all the subscription are within the same tenant, it won't matter whether the adf pipeline is in same subscription or not. The process to get the status would remain the same

Comment: tenant means the purchased organization right, we have implement the pipe lines or call the trigger pipelines to setup the dependency. is it my understanding correct.